# Bucardo doesn't sync anymore

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, bucardo

I installed Bucardo and everything was fine, till after some days I checked if the sync was properly replicating my data and I saw that it didn't!

Checking bucardo log I can find this warning:

```
MCP Warning: Source database for sync "sync_name" has column "column_name" of table "table_name" but target database "db_slave" does not
MCP Validation of sync FAILED
MCP Active syncs: 0
MCP Entering main loop
```

Why bucardo stopped to sync? And why if I check with "bucardo status" I can see that the state of the sync is "Good" ?

If I check validation with:

```
bucardo validate sync_name
```

the output is:

```
Validating sync sync_name ... OK
```

But it's not ok of course!

Is the problem related to the fact that I ran a migration on my master db?
How can I fix this problem, making bucardo sync again?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Richard Huxton suggest, I can find the answer inside [Bucardo Documentation.](https://bucardo.org/wiki/Bucardo/FAQ#Can_Bucardo_replicate_DDL.3F)

As DDL is the way as the database schema is manipulated, what exactly I have to look for is:

**Can Bucardo replicate DDL?**

**The answer is not.**

So if the schema of the source database change, Bucardo will stop syncing.

In my case, I am using Bucardo because my source database is on AWS RDS and so I can't configure manually Postgres enjoying his [Streaming Replication](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Streaming_Replication)

Answer (score 2):

Do you know what, sometimes, just sometimes it helps to (1) skim the documentation the project provides and (2) read the error message which tells you exactly what it isn't happy with.

https://bucardo.org/wiki/Bucardo/FAQ#Can_Bucardo_replicate_DDL.3F